# Submitting Dynamic Form Fields to mysql via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have created a dynamic form and I am trying to send the form data to mysql through PHP but its not working. Data is not getting sent even from the very first row without adding a dynamic row. I'm new to this topic, so I'm out of ideas to solve it. How can I make this form a correct one and send accurate data to mysql?

In my form I have 3 fields that are not dynamic.

Here is the form code:

```php
<form name="newbillform" method="POST" action="save_purchase_details.php">
    <table style=" border:1px solid black" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px" align="center" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; fontsize:20px" align="center">
                ADD NEW PURCHASE RECORD
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" name="p_date"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Invoice Number:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="invoice_no" size="50">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Balance:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="balance" size="50">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h2 style="padding-left:10px;">Enter Product Details Below:-</h2>
    <table id="product_details" style="margin-top:8px;" align='center' border='1' width="900px">
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty[]" value="" placeholder="Quantity" size="6">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" placeholder="Pack" size="6">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="item_name[]" value="" placeholder="Item Name" size="16">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="batch[]" value="" placeholder="Batch" size="6">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="expiry[]" value="" placeholder="Expiry" size="6">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mrp[]" value="" placeholder="M.R.P" size="6">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="rate[]" value="" placeholder="Rate" size="6">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="vat[]" value="" placeholder="VAT" size="6">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="discount[]" value="" placeholder="Discount" size="6">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="button-add-row" onclick="add_row();" value="ADD ROW" size="8">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <center>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_row" value="SUBMIT">
    </center>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add_row()
    {
        $rowno = $("#product_details tr").length;
        $rowno = $rowno + 1;
        $("#product_details tr:last").after("<tr id='row"+$rowno+"'><td><input   type='text' name='qty[]' placeholder='Quantity' size='6'></td><td><input type='text' name='pack[]' placeholder='Pack' size='6'></td><td><input type='text' placeholder='Item Name' name='item_name[]' size='16'></td><td><input type='text' name='batch[]' placeholder='Batch' size='6'></td><td><input type='text' name='expiry[]' placeholder='Expiry' size='6'></td><td><input type='text' name='mrp[]' placeholder='M.R.P' size='6'></td><td><input type='text' name='rate[]' placeholder='Rate' size='6'></td><td><input type='text' name='vat[]' placeholder='VAT' size='6'></td><td><input type='text' name='discount[]' placeholder='Discount' size='6'></td><td><input type='button' class='button-add-row' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('row"+$rowno+"')></td></tr>");
    }

    function delete_row(rowno)
    {
        $('#'+rowno).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("store_records",$connect) or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['submit_row']))
{
    $amount;
    $grand_total;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['item_name']); $i++)
    {
        $qty         = $_POST['qty'][$i];
        $p_date      = $_POST['p_date'];
        $invoice_no  = $_POST['invoice_no'];
        $balance     = $_POST['balance'];
        $pack        = $_POST['pack'][$i];
        $item_name   = $_POST['item_name'][$i];
        $batch       = $_POST['batch'][$i];
        $expiry      = $_POST['expiry'][$i];
        $mrp         = $_POST['mrp'][$i];
        $rate        = $_POST['rate'][$i];
        $vat         = $_POST['vat'][$i];
        $discount    = $_POST['discount'][$i];
        $amount      = $balance+($qty*$rate)-$discount;
        $grand_total = $amount+(($amount*$vat)/100);

        $query =mysql_query("insert into bill_records values('', '$p_date', '$invoice_no', '$balance', '$qty','$pack','$item_name', '$batch', '$expiry', '$mrp', '$rate', '$vat', '$discount', '$amount', '$grand_total')");     
    }
}

?>
```

It would be of great help. Thank You..

Comment: what is the error you get, mention it

Comment: What you are doing with `mysql_query` makes you vulnerable to SQL Injection. **Be extremely careful about this.**

Comment: i'll fix that #giampy.. the problem is, the page doesnt show any errors, but the data doesnt get submitted either..

Comment: echo your Sql Query to check what values are going in database table